# Merge sort recursive algorithm in Bash cannot exit and return value

Tags: bash, shell, mergesort

I'm implementing a merge sort algorithm in bash, but looks like it loops forever and gives error on m1 and m2 subarrays. It's a bit hard to stop loop in conditions since I have to use echo and not return. Anyone have any idea why this happens?

```
MergeSort (){
  
  local a=("$@")

  if [ ${#a[@]} -eq 1 ]
  then
    echo ${a[@]}
  elif [ ${#a[@]} -eq 2 ]
  then
    if [ ${a[0]} -gt ${a[1]} ]
    then
      local t=(${a[0]} ${a[1]})
      echo ${t[@]}
    else
      echo ${a[@]}
    fi
  else

    local p=($(( ${#a[@]} / 2 )))
    local m1=$(MergeSort "${a[@]::p}")
    local m2=$(MergeSort "${a[@]:p}")
    local ret=()

    while true
    do
      if [ "${#m1[@]}" > 0 ] && [ "${#m2[@]}" > 0 ]
      then
        if [ ${m1[0]} <= ${m2[0]} ]
        then
          ret+=(${m1[0]})
          m1=${m1[@]:1}
        else
          ret+=(${m2[0]})
          m2=${m2[@]:1}
        fi
      elif [ ${#m1[@]} > 0 ]
      then
        ret+=(${ret[@]} ${m1[@]})
        unset m1
      elif [ ${#m2[@]} > 0 ]
      then
        ret+=(${ret[@]} ${m2[@]})
        unset m2
      else
        break
      fi
    done
  fi

  echo ${ret[@]}
}

a=(6 5 6 4 2)
b=$(MergeSort "${a[@]}")
echo ${b[@]}
```

Comment: You're mixing operators. If you use `[ ... ]` and numbers, you have to use `-gt`, `-lt`, `-ge` and `-le`, but you sometimes use `>` or `<=`.

Comment: Since you're using Bash (arrays), you could switch to the more convenient `(( ... ))` everywhere.

Comment: And looping forever mean you never hit the `break` in the `while true`. You can use `set -x` or `set -vx` to see what goes on.

Comment: `m2=${m2[@]:1}` flattens the array into a string; you have to use `m2=("${m2[@]:1}")` instead.

Comment: Also, have a look at everything https://www.shellcheck.net/ tells you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I did all that, but the problem now seems to be `if [ "${m1[0]}" -le "${m2[0]}" ]`. As far as I can understand from `set -vx`, it looks like there is happening an array comparison rather than integer. The error notes this too: `integer expression expected`. This is my current code: https://pastebin.com/dY8rszxe

Comment: When you do `m1=("$(MergeSort "${a[@]::p}")")`, `m1` becomes an array with a single element; you have to unquote `$(...)` in this case.

Comment: (My bad, as that was my recommendation above...)

Comment: Even unquoting and leaving it like this `m1=$(MergeSort "${a[@]::p}")` still leads to the same error `mergesort.bash: line 32: [: 5 9: integer expression expected`. So the wrong comparison is happening again

Comment: Also that leads to a lot of numbers echoing in the end

Comment: I made a correction on line 42 and 46 removing the plus sign, leading to less numbers echoing :P

Comment: From the `set -vx` I can see this `++ echo '3 2 6 4 6' '1 3 5 9'` as the last echo which seems wrong

Comment: It has to be `m1=($(MergeSort "${a[@]::p}"))`, you still want an array in the end

Comment: That worked for me! Thank you a lot for your time, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your shell script:

- you should use `-gt` instead of `>` for numeric comparisons on array lengths
- `<=` is not a supported string comparison operator. You should use `<` and quote it as `'<'`, or better use `'>'` and transpose actions to preserve sort stability.
- there is no need for `local t`, and your code does not swap the arguments. Just use `echo ${a[1]} ${a[0]}`
- you must parse the result of recursive calls to `MergeSort` as arrays: `local m1=($(MergeSort "${a[@]::p}"))`
- when popping initial elements from `m1` and `m2`, you must reparse as arrays: `m1=(${m1[@]:1})`
- instead of `ret+=(${ret[@]} ${m1[@]})` you should just append the elements with `ret+=(${m1[@]})` and instead of `unset m1`, you should `break` from the loop. As a matter of fact, if either array is empty you should just append the remaining elements from both arrays and `break`.
- furthermore, the `while true` loop should be simplified as a `while [ ${#m1[@]} -gt 0 ] && [ ${#m2[@]} -gt 0 ]` loop followed by the tail handling.
- the final `echo ${ret[@]}` should be moved inside the `else` branch of the last `if`
- to handle embedded spaces, you should stringize all expansions but as the resulting array is expanded with `echo` embedded spaces that appear in the output are indistinguishable from word breaks. There is no easy workaround for this limitation.

Here is a modified version:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

MergeSort (){

  local a=("$@")

  if [ ${#a[@]} -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "${a[@]}"
  elif [ ${#a[@]} -eq 2 ]; then
    if [ "${a[0]}" '>' "${a[1]}" ]; then
      echo "${a[1]}" "${a[0]}"
    else
      echo "${a[@]}"
    fi
  else

    local p=($(( ${#a[@]} / 2 )))
    local m1=($(MergeSort "${a[@]::p}"))
    local m2=($(MergeSort "${a[@]:p}"))
    local ret=()

    while [ ${#m1[@]} -gt 0 ] && [ ${#m2[@]} -gt 0 ]; do
      if [ "${m1[0]}" '>' "${m2[0]}" ]; then
        ret+=("${m2[0]}")
        m2=("${m2[@]:1}")
      else
        ret+=("${m1[0]}")
        m1=("${m1[@]:1}")
      fi
    done
    echo "${ret[@]}" "${m1[@]}" "${m2[@]}"
  fi
}

a=(6 5 6 4 2 a c b c aa 00 0 000)
b=($(MergeSort "${a[@]}"))
echo "${b[@]}"
```

Output: `0 00 000 2 4 5 6 6 a aa b c c`